Hodge structure of a blowup
I've been reading Voisin's Hodge theory and complex algebraic geometry, volume. In theorem 7.31 on page 181 she states that

The commutativity of the diagram of long exact sequences of relative cohomology (7.9) then implies that the natural map $ (\tau^*,j_*) $ is surjective, and the injectivity of $\tau^*_{X,U}$ in degree $k-1$ shows that the kernel of this map is $Im(j_{Z*},-\alpha).$

I am very confused about the surjectivity and the kernel of this map. I tried to prove the following proposition

The following commutative diagram of vector spaces
diagram
(there is a trouble when I type the tikzcd diagram so I have to upload the picture)
satisfying
(1) two rows are exact sequences;
(2) $\phi_1,\phi_4$ are isomorphisms;
(3) $\phi_2,\phi_3$ are injections;
then $(\phi_3 , g_2) \colon A_3 \oplus B_2 \rightarrow B_3$ is surjective.

However I can only show that $(A_3 \oplus B_2) / \ker(\phi_3,g_2) = A_3 \oplus (B_2 / \phi_2(\ker f_2))$. Is the proposition right? If it is right, how to prove it? If it is not right, how to show the surjectivity of $ (\tau^*,j_*) $?
Here is the full text in Voisin's book.
page 180
page 181
